When is the proximal mapping of a function convex?
I'm studying optimization and trying to understand the properties of proximal mappings. Specifically, I'm interested in the conditions under which the proximal mapping of a function is convex.
Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \cup$ $\{ -\infty, \infty\}$ be a function. The proximal mapping of $f$ is defined as:
$
\text{prox}_{f}(x)$ = $  \arg\min_{u \in \mathbb{R}^{n}} \left\{ f(u) + \frac{1}{2} \| u - x \|^{2} \right\}$
I have the following questions:
General Convexity: Under what conditions on $f$ is $\text{prox}_f(x)$ a convex function of $x$?
Specific Examples: Are there any well-known classes of functions (e.g., convex, strongly convex, Lipschitz continuous gradient, etc.) for which the proximal mapping is guaranteed to be convex?
Non-convex Functions: If $f$ is non-convex, can the proximal mapping still be convex under certain circumstances?
Any insights or references would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Convexity is typically defined for functions with values in $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb R \cup {\pm \infty}$. However, $\operatorname{prox}_f \colon \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$.

Following @gerw , are you probably more interested in conditions under which the Moreau envelope is convex? In this case, convexity would be sufficient.

Note that the proximity operator is not necessarily single-valued for non-convex functions. It could be set-valued.
